# After Migration, images show up on a preview of the page but not the actual page

Tags: images, migration, previews

I'm helping out with a website that got a little bit broken when they changed hosts. The images stopped working for some parts of the website, so I am going through and trying to fix them. I somehow managed to fix them in a way that it works when I preview the changes to the page, but when I update the page and view it the pictures don't load. I've uploaded images of the difference in source code from the previewed site to the finished site.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhzUe.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the plugin I was using to lazy-load was broken so disabling that made it work!